# bash 'read' timeout do not wait for input when using pipeline

Tags: bash, pipe

```
## bash script  
foo(){

    sleep 0.0001
    read -s -t 0.0002 var  ## get the pipeline input if have 
    if [ -n "$var" ];then
        echo "has pipe input"
    fi

    if [ $# -gt 0 ];then
        echo "has std input"
    fi
    read -s -t 30 var1  #1 # expect wait for 30 seconds , but acturaly not
    echo "failed"     
    read -s -t 30 var2  #2  
    echo "failed again"
}

echo "ok1"|  foo "ok"

## output: 
has pipe input
has std input
failed
failed again
```

if the foo has pipeline input ,  the read command at #1 & #2 will return immediately without waiting for input TIMEOUT

in my real script there are three needs :

1 made function could accept pipeline input and parameter at the same time (cause i want my function can take configuration from pipeline input , i think that will be nice for me. for example: )

```
foo(){
    local config
    sleep 0.0001
    read -t 0.0002 config
    eval "$config"
}

then i can pass configuration like this 
foo para1 para2 <<EOF
G_TIMEOUT=300
G_ROW_SPACE=2
G_LINE_NUM=10
EOF
```

2 in my function i need to read user input from keyboard（ i need  interactive with user by using *read* ）

3 wait for user input should has a timeout ( i want to implament a screensaver ,if there is no action after TIMEOUT seconds passed from user, will call screensaver script , and after any keydown , screensaver will return , and again to wait for use input

> if there is a way to redirect pipeline input to fd3 after i get the pipeline input ,and then close fd3 to make pipe broken , then reopen fd0 to standard input (keyboard) and wait for user input ?

Comment: Why do you believe this is working incorrectly? What is the behaviour you are expecting? Most likely you are misinterpreting the meaning of read's `-t` flag. Also be aware that read will read from standard input and not arguments.

Comment: acturally my script has there needs

1  made function could accept pipeline input and stdinput at the same time 
2  in my function i need to wait for user input  
3  wait for user input has a  timeout

Comment: So what are you expecting?

Comment: i expecting function can take pipeline input to variables , then use read to get user keyboard input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because  function foo has pipeline input , so in child process , the input fd been redirected to pipeline automaticly , just redirect the standard input to keyboard(/proc/pid/0) after get the pipeline input ,will solve the problem
>
> thanks for those guys give me that clue , it is not read command problem ,it is fd problem acturaly

```
foo(){                  
local config

sleep 0.0001
read -t 0.0002 config

if [ -n "$config" ];then
config=$(cat -)
fi
echo "$config"
exec 3</dev/tty
read -t 10 -u 3 input
echo "success!"
}
```

> a better approche:

```
foo(){                  
local config

sleep 0.0001
read -t 0.0002 config

if [ -n "$config" ];then
config=$(cat -)
fi
exec 0<&-   ## close current pipeline input 
exec 0</dev/tty   ##reopen input fd with standard input 

read -t 10 input  ##read will wait for input for keyboard :) good !
echo "success!"
}
```

> furthermore if i can detect current input is pipe or standard input , i colud not use read config to judge if there are pipeline input , but how to fullfill that ? [ -t 0 ] is a good idea
>
> a better approche:

```
foo(){                  
local config

if [ ! -t 0 ];then
    config=$(cat -)
    exec 0<&-   ## close current pipeline input 
    exec 0</dev/tty   ##reopen input fd with standard input
fi
 
read -t 10 input  ##read will wait for input for keyboard :) great !
echo "success!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't wait for input because it has reached the end of the pipe.

`echo "ok1" | ...` writes a single line to the pipe, then closes it. The first `read` in the function reads `ok1` into `var`. All other `read` calls return immediately because there is no more data to read and no chance of more data appearing later because the write end of the pipe has already been closed.

If you want the pipe to stay open, you have to do something like

```
{ echo ok1; sleep 40; echo ok2; } | foo
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extra to the [answer of melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53391796/8344060) you can see this when executing the following line:

```
$ echo foo | { read -t 10 var1; echo $?; read -t 10 var2; echo $?; }
0
1
$ read -t 1 var; echo $?
142
```

This line outputs the return codes of `read` and the manual states

> The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out (in which case the return code is greater than 128), or  an  invalid
>                 file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u
>
> **<sub>source: `man bash`</sub>**

From this we see that the second read in the first command fails because EOF is reached.

Comment: my screensaver has catch the 142 , and error handler has catch the 1 , i had already take into concideration the return code of the read , but i think it is not work for my circumstances , i need read in function wait for user input